# Replacing Bath Spout

Tags: plumbing

Our bath spout has been dripping for quite some time so I’m wanting to replace it.

It unscrews and the picture is what I’m left with. I think I know which type to buy but it’s still dripping even when the spout is off. It drips from both the right and left side of the brass thing.

Do I need to replace that before replacing the spout.[image]![enter image description

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is: **You do not need to replace the spout**.

Water drips from the spout because the valve or valves are leaking.

Replacing the spout will not fix the leak.

The leaky valve will still allow water to drip from the new spout.

To stop the leak you must repair or replace the valve.

Answer (score 0):

If your bath spout is dripping it's because the valve/valves are leaking. You will need replace your cartridge if it's a single handle or washers if it's a double handle.

Comment: What part is the valve? The brass part?

Comment: Include a picture.

Comment: Ok. So that needs replaced, even if it’s dripping on the brass part?

Comment: It’s a single handle faucet so I’ll need to figure out how to take that off. Is the cartridge inside of the handle or visible when I get the handle off?

Comment: Not in the handle, partially visible  when handle is removed.  Post a picture of the faucet.

Comment: @pantherguy We can not walk you through the process step by step in the comments section of this site. Do some research on repairing single handle shower valves on YouTube and you will have better understanding of how they work and how to disassemble them. ( some have cartridges but not all )  Then you can ask another question here if you have specific problem with that repair.

Comment: This question has been answered, Please choose one of the two correct answers and then when you learn about your valve and how it work and what is needed to repair it you can post any additional questions.